# How to get the hour, minutes and seconds

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

```
const boost::posix_time::ptime now= boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

year_ = now.date().year();
month_ = now.date().month();
day_ = now.date().day();
```

This is how I get the years, months and day out of boost::posix_time::ptime, but I can't figure out how to get the hour, minutes and seconds. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

```
now.time_of_day().hours(); 
now.time_of_day().minutes();
now.time_of_day().seconds();
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the source in the documentation so I know where to find it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

```
Hours_=now.time_duration().hours;
...
```